# How to access git-repo from ARGO-WF using HTTP-access-token?

Tags: git, argo-workflows

I would like to access a git-repo from ARGO using an HTTP-access token. Below workflow works perfectly-fine, as it is free-access. But how do I have to adapt this workflow if I need to access a repo requiring verification via HTTP-access-token?

In the terminal the verification would look like this:

```
git clone -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Bearer [HTTP-TOKEN]" https://code.company.com/scm/tc_pbms/report_configs.git
```

This workflow works fine in case of no verification:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: input-artifact-git-
spec:
  entrypoint: git-clone
  templates:
  - name: git-clone
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: argo-source
        path: /src
        git:
          repo: https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
    container:
      image: alpine
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cd /src; ls"]
      workingDir: /src
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-creds
type: Opaque
stringData:
  username: my-github-username
  password: my-github-access-token
```

```
spec:
  entrypoint: git-clone
  templates:
  - name: git-clone
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: argo-source
        path: /src
        git:
          repo: https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
          usernameSecret:
            name: git-creds
            key: username
          passwordSecret:
            name: git-creds
            key: password
    container:
      image: alpine
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cd /src; ls"]
      workingDir: /src
```

This refers to a secret that you create, called `git-creds` with two keys `username` and `password`. The password can be a GitHub personal access token.

Alternatively, (or if you're not using GitHub) you can store your token in a secret, mount it as environment variable "HTTP_TOKEN", then run git cli. Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-creds
type: Opaque
stringData:
  http-token: t0p-secret
```

```
spec:
  entrypoint: git-clone
  templates:
  - name: git-clone
    outputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: source
        path: /src
    container:
      image: "alpine/git"
      env:
      - name: HTTP_TOKEN
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: git-creds
            key: http-token
      command: [sh, -c]
      args:
      - |
      git clone -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Bearer $HTTP_TOKEN" https://code.company.com/scm/tc_pbms/report_configs.git /src
```